# How to disable the menu item after specific time in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

lets say i have a  menu item for 'airline reservation' and it should get inactive after 4 o'clock then what should be done for this in joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any thing on joomla.

The right thing you need to do on this case is 
what function you need to close after your end time.
click the menu - >in that page check the time and block the things.
This is best practise.

Other way is :

You can achieve this by using Javascript. But this is not at all a good practice.
Get the local time of the user and compare its with your disable time(4 o'clock). 
This has some complication with time zones to but you can do it with js.
Then use jquery to remove the link of that menu and .
like:

```
jQuery("#menu_id").attr('href','javascript:;');
```

There is no concept of menu item expiry based on time you can give some access level  for menus
like registered,public etc..

Hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no publish_up publish_down for a menu but you ould run a cron job to unpublish it if it is consistently turned off at the same time everyday.

Comment: Thanks Elin for the suggetion...as per you say i have downloaded the   'JPrc Cronjobs' extension for joomla 2.5..but i am facing problems while using it,like how to configure it like what is Task type,Command to run options in it etc. and make it work on the site....

Comment: It's the same task as you would use on the toolbar. That is probably publish.